# How to find which module is active for network control?

Tags: netplan

I have an Ubuntu VPS and I want to change its IP address and gateway.

But none of the network commands work on this system.

- `ifconfig` works and shows just `lo`.
- `ifup` command not found.

```
/etc/sysconfig/interfaces
```

shows `ifupdown` is replaced by `netplan(5)`

Then `netplan` command not found. Also, `Network-Manager` command not found too.

So how should I restart the network on this machine?
Currently I login using the console.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu or RHEL or CentOS?

Comment: it is Ubuntu.  I could add an IP using this command:   sudo ifconfig ens32 up 192.168.1.100    I am trying to add a route.so that I get internet and reinstall packages.

Comment: I added gateway and I have internet now: route add default gw 1.2.3.4  . now I should findout the active network module to make this ip permanent after reboots.

Comment: Install netplan with `sudo apt install netplan`

Answer (score 0):

If ifconfig did not show your interface then it seems you did not have any valid network configuration for it in netplan. You probably have an existing yaml file under /etc/netplan which you can edit to add your interface and its addresses.  This may be as simple as replacing `dhcp: true` in the config with appropriate `addresses:` and `routes:` stanzas.